# Is it possible to manually trigger a stage when using YAML Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

With Azure DevOps release pipelines, it is possible to re-deploy a stage that either failed or succeeded. With the new Azure Pipelines in YAML, I don't see any way to do that from the UI other than re-triggering the whole pipeline.

Is that intended? I would expect to see a "re-deploy" or "re-run" button on a stage like we had with release pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is a basic function, I am afraid that unfortunately, at the moment it is not possible.

There is a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/578950/re-run-a-single-stage-in-a-multi-stage-pipeline.html) about it, you can up vote there:

[image]

Comment: It also in the road map: https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1454027

Comment: Really good to know, thanks again. I should have thought about looking at their roadmap